# Datatable Controls in dialog header/footer

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, datatables

I have a DataTable with 3 controls; General Search, Pagination, and Info (i.e. 'Showing 1 to 10 of 88 Entries' ).  I want to place these controls in the header/footer of a jQuery Dialog window.

DataTables provides an options called [sDOM](http://datatables.net/ref#sDOM), which lets one specify where to put DataTable's controls.  But, I want to put the controls in the header and footer of a modal, which can not be done with [sDOM](http://datatables.net/ref#sDOM).

The General Search control can be created with [fnFilter](http://datatables.net/ref#fnFilter), which is easy enough.

I think Pagination, and Info will require writing a [custom pagination plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination), which I would like to avoid.

This is my current progress on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluegeek9bluegeek9/s2q7D/3/).

```js
$('#modal').dialog({
modal: true,
    "height": 570,
    "width": 1170,
autoOpen: false,
auto: true,
dialogClass: "myDialog",
create: function () {
    $(".myDialog").append('<div id="dialogFooter" class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_X_info"></div></div>');
    }
});

var dataTableJS = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sDom": 'it<\"F\"p>"',
});

$("#modal").dialog("open");
```

Comment: I'd love to know the reason my question was down voted.

Comment: Yes, at least the downvoter could explain. Cannot see why either, now there is balance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it backwards :)

1. Create the dataTable
2. Create the modal
3. Move the autogenerated controls from the dataTable to the footer (or whatever)

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/xK3TK/**

I Have in the example placed the footer on top and included jQuery UI css (and you have BTW forgotten to close the modal markup `</div>`)

```js
var dataTableJS = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    //"sDom": 'it<\"F\"p>"',
});

$('#modal').dialog({
    modal: true,
        "height": 570,
        "width": 770,
    autoOpen: false,
    auto: true,
    dialogClass: "myDialog",
    create: function () {
        $("#dataTable_info").detach().appendTo('#dialogFooter');
        $("#dataTable_paginate").detach().appendTo('#dialogFooter');
        $("#dataTable_length").detach().appendTo('#dialogFooter');
        $("#dataTable_filter").detach().appendTo('#dialogFooter');
    }
});

$("#modal").dialog("open");
```